# Running java project in command line with user input

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I have a java project which I'm running in the command line. I have created a .bat file to run the project. However my java project must take in 4 arguments before it starts running which works like this in my `.bat` file....

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
java -jar dist/prog.jar 5 6 7 3

pause

(5 6 7 3 being the arguments passed to String[] args)
```

However, I do not want to input the specific arguments to be passed to `String[] args` in the `.bat` file, I want it to be passed by user input so that I can enter in different values as my arguments in the command line each time I run it. How can I do this?

Comment: [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Use `SET /P`. See the command help for details: `SET /?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use % replacements to pass in the parameters given to the .cmd

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
REM %* forwards all parameters
java -jar dist/Election_real.jar %*
pause
```

And then call `yourcmd.cmd 5 6 7 8`

If you want to *ask* for these parameters, you'd go

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
set /p nr1=Enter Nr1:
set /p nr2=Enter Nr2:
set /p nr3=Enter Nr3:
set /p nr4=Enter Nr4: 
java -jar dist/Election_real.jar %nr1% %nr2% %nr3% %nr4%
pause
```

Comment: Okay so I added %* and it didn't wait for me to enter in the arguments. Basically in my Java project if have an if statement that says if the length of String[] args =0 then it will run the project with default arguments. So as soon as I'm running my .bat file, even with java -jar dist/Election_real.jar %* it is just running my project straight away with the default arguments rather than waiting for me to input my custom arguments

Comment: Then I completely misunderstood your request - with %* you *pass the arguments* from .cmd to  java. If you want your .cmd to ask for those... then set /P is the way to go. I'll edit.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you! It worked! Last thing, just me being fussy but now my user input for example would look  like this for example: 5, 4(on next line), 2(on next line), 7(on next line)....How can I make it so all 4 inputs are inputted on one line, so 4 5 6 7 for example

Comment: Tale away the echo off, enter all 4 5 6 7 as nr1 and see the result. As %nr1% has not been escaped with " it will probably pass in 7 args into your main then...

Comment: You're well aware of cause that all of this could be done inside your main () as well

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work now! And no I didn't realise...would probably have caused me a lot less stress haha

Comment: If the answer solved your question it would be nice if you accepted it.